# Are two integers equal in SOME base?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

Disclaimer: this problem is purely for fun. There may already be a solution (I've searched, no luck). I have several questions below, I'd appreciate an answer to any of them. RIYL...

I was inspired by a Three Stooges video I saw earlier, where it's shown that 13x7 = 28. You may have seen it. But I started wondering: is there SOME "base" in which this equation is true (I put base in quotations because I'm using the term in the wrong sense..see the final paragraph for what I mean)?

The answer is clearly no, if we define multiplication the same as for integers. If you break up 13 into "base" i, say `13 = 1*i+3`, and `28 = 2*i+8`, the multiplication factor of 7 ensures equality won't happen.

Okay, but now suppose you want to ask the question, is there some base where two numbers are equal, say 8 = 10 (I'm probably using the term "base" wrong, sorry for that)?

What I mean is, if we write 8 = 008 = 0*8^2+0*8+8, 10 = 010 = 0*8^2+1*8^1+0, then according to my (clearly wrong) usage of base, we have equality. I wrote some simple code, up to 3 digit numbers, to verify this. But my code sucks.

```
 ''' We define two numbers, such that n1 > n2...tho I'm flexible'''
n1 = "013"
n2 = "025"

''' Set the numbers as arrays. '''
num1 = list(range(len(n1)))
num2 = list(range(len(n2)))

for i in range(len(n1)):
     num1[i] = int(n1[i])
for i in range(len(n2)):
    num2[i] = int(n2[i])
''' Now we loop until we find a match, or no match is possible. '''
i = 1
j = 0
while True:
    t1=(num1[0]*(i**2)+num1[1]*i+num1[2])
    t2=(num2[0]*(i**2)+num2[1]*i+num2[2])
    ''' We need some way to check if t1 > t2 changes to t1 < t2 at some point
        or vise-versa -> then we know no match is possible '''
    if(i == 1):
        if t1>t2:
            j = 0
        else: j = 1
    if(t1==t2):        
        print("The numbers are equal in base %d" % i)
        break
    if(t2 > t1 and j == 0):
        print("No base possible! After %d steps" % i)
        break
    if(t1 > t2 and j == 1):
        print("No base possible! After %d steps" % i)
        break
    i=i+1
    if (i > 2**6):
        print("your search might be hopeless")
        break
```

Sorry if your eyes hurt from that hideous code. I didn't even use numpy arrays. What I'm wondering is,

1. Has this problem been solved before, for arbitrary digits? If not..
2. I wanted to be flexible about the number of digits entered in `n1` and `n2`. Is there a more clever way to define the functions `t1` and `t2` so that they adaptively expand in base `i`, depending on the number of digits entered?
3. Performance-wise I'm sure there's a better way to do my main iteration. This is the fun part for me, combined with the answer to part 2. Any suggestions?
4. If it happens that t1 and t2 forever remain ordered the same, as in the example from the code, the iteration will play out 2^^6 times. The iteration number was chosen arbitrarily, but one could imagine if we extended to many digits, one might need even more iterations! Surely there's a more clever way to stop the iteration?
5. Is my stopping condition just wrong?

Thanks so much for reading. This is not a homework assignment and the answers are probably completely useless. I'm just interested in seeing a real coder's take on it. It would be neat if this wasn't an already-solved problem. Much love.

Comment: Your example isn't equal in base 8, it's two different numbers represented in two different bases (except 8 isn't a digit in base 8). You can always do this, but it doesn't mean what you're asking.

Comment: To convert a number in base 10 to a number in some other base, you can use `int(str(number), base)`.

Comment: I don't really understand, are you asking about two numbers in different bases having the same representation at some common base?

Comment: I guess I was unclear, or just stupid. I meant do two different integers, if we add heading 0's to them, equal according to the type of expansion I do in t1 and t2. I'm clearly using the wrong terminology. @Bill the Lizard, I tried to change the phrasing above, since I clearly got the nomenclature wrong.

Comment: @Amoss 's answer below, without providing any code, actually answers my question. For 4 digit-integers, exact solutions can be found, though they may be complex-valued. I was looking for integer-valued solutions for the "base", but I'm content to leave that bit unresolved. Higher than four digits, we still recast the problem as a polynomial equation, which can be solved by numerical root finding techniques. Great! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the problem simpler by applying a little bit of number of theory. Taking your first example 13x7=28 we can expand this out into an explicit polynomial over the base: (1n+3)*7=2n+8.

If this solution has real roots then the roots are values of n (bases) for which the equation is true. If you like this sort of problem then you should read Computational Number Theory by Shoup. It's a fun book.

Comment: Very cool Amoss, thanks for the suggestion. I would imagine if we go above order 4 digit integers, so by analogy fourth order polynomials, wouldn't this be nontrivial in general? I'll have to check out the book.

Comment: It's possible that it would get easier - the higher degree polynomials would make the search space sparser, but the easy answer would be that they could not be satisfied. It's been a while - it was a bit of luck that I recognised your problem.

Comment: Interesting, and counter intuitive. Applied math guy here, I know ~ no number theory. My first thought was there must be somenumber theoryanswer to this lol. In regression for example higher dimensionality makes things really tough because of the topological complexity in the searches. I won't ask you to elaborate on how is easier in higher dimensions, I'll probably just look up the book you recommended. I've run into some higher dimensional root finding problems recently, related to hyperbolic PDES, so I've gotta figure out a way to do this anyways. Thanks again and best wishes.